# Como puedo ejecutar acciones de un programa poniendo un '-'

Tags: java, cmd

Me preguntaba como los **compiladores como GCC o el de Java**, podían ejecutar diferentes acciones con solo poner un **'-'**.

**e.g:**

[image: Como se muestra en la imagen]

**o también**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**en gcc es igual**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EDIT:** Cito el ejemplo de gcc, no por que quiera implementarlo en un programa de C++, sino para ponerlo como un simple ejemplo (valga la redundancia). En el fondo solo quiero saber como poder añadirlo a un programa de **Java**.

Comment: En qué lenguaje estás programando? No olvides utilizar las etiquetas relevantes en tus preguntas. Por otro lado, sugiero que recortes las imagenes o simplemente incluyas el texto de la consola como texto, y no como imagen. Un saludo.

Comment: por favor haz una pregunta por cada lenguaje si no será una pregunta demasiado amplia

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para lograr lo que quieres, debes evaluar los parámetros que tu programa ha recibido al invocarse desde la línea de comandos.

En java, por ejemplo, estos parámetros llegan como argumentos del método `main()`, como un arreglo de cadenas de caracteres, que tradicionalmente se llama `args` (de argumentos).

Básicamente, entonces, evalúas lo que viene en cada elemento de ese arreglo. Mira este ejemplo sencillo donde itero por los argumentos. Si no he recibido ningún argumento válido, imprimo la *ayuda* del programa:

```
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        boolean correcto = false;
        int result = 0;
        for (String arg : args) {
          switch (arg) {
            case "-opcion1":
              System.out.println("Felicitaciones, ha utilizado la opcion1");
              correcto = true;
              break;
            case "-opcion2":
              System.out.println("Felicitaciones, ha utilizado la opcion2");
              correcto = true;
              break;
          }
        }
        if (!correcto) {
            System.out.println("Uso: programa [-opcion1] [-opcion2]");
            result = 1;
        }
    }
```

Al invocarlo, obtengo estas respuestas:

```
> java MiClase

Uso: programa [-opcion1] [-opcion2]

> java MiClase -opcion1
Felicitaciones, ha utilizado la opcion1

> java MiClase -opcion2 -opcion1
Felicitaciones, ha utilizado la opcion2
Felicitaciones, ha utilizado la opcion1
```

Sobre esta idea base, hay bibliotecas que son de gran ayuda para realizar software robusto en esta área haciendo una programación relativamente sencilla. Por ejemplo [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) o [picocli](https://github.com/remkop/picocli).

Comment: Gracias por la solución.